# How can I get number in html and write it another html tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, function

```
<div id="element1" onclick="add();">10</div>
<div id="element2" onclick="add();">56</div>
<div id="element3" onclick="add();">42</div>
<div id="element4" onclick="add();">109</div>
<div id="element5" onclick="add();">45</div>

<div id="values"></div>
```

When user click any div will taken number value in html for example user click element3 42 number taken and written in html what id is values. After when user click any div, will taken number again for example element4 109 taken and written but 42 will not be deleted. Like this;

42,109,...

How can I do this with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this

```
$('div[id^="element"]').click(function(){ // bind only on div whose if starts with element
  var existing = $('#values').text();
  $('#values').html(existing ? existing + ',' + $(this).text() : $(this).text());
});
```

Note that you should remove  `onclick="add();"` from your existing div. I could have proposed you to create a `add` function but the best practice is to separate the code from the HTML by binding the event listeners using the jQuery binding functions.

Answer (score 3):

First, you remove the `onclick` handlers. Then you do this:

```
$("[id^=element]").click(function() {
    $("#values").text($(this).text());
});
```

Breaking it down:

1. `$("[id^=element]")` looks up all elements on the page that have an `id` value [*starting with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) "element".
2. `.click(function() { ... })` [hooks up a click handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the matched elements.
3. `$("#values")` looks up the element with the `id` "values".
4. `.text(...)` [sets the text](http://api.jquery.com/text) of the matched element.
5. `$(this).text()` wraps the `this` value (which inside a jQuery `click` handler is the element on which you hooked the click event) in a jQuery wrapper, then [gets its text](http://api.jquery.com/text) from it.

Even cleaner would be if you can remove the `elementX` `id` values from the elements entirely and replace them with a class, e.g.:

```
<div class="source">10</div>
<div class="source">56</div>
<div class="source">42</div>
<div class="source">109</div>
<div class="source">45</div>

<div id="values"></div>
```

Then:

```
$(".source").click(function() {
    $("#values").text($(this).text());
});
```

Or you could have them all in a container and use some kind of structural selector. The point is you can find the elements to hook the event on using any CSS3 selector (and then some).

It's well worth spending just an hour reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com). It literally takes just an hour or so, and it's hugely useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use onclick with jQuery. Second, unless you are using the id="element1" part somewhere else , try not use an id for each element. This is more recommended:

```
<div class="clickable">10</div>
<div class="clickable">56</div>
<div class="clickable">42</div>
<div class="clickable">109</div>
<div class="clickable">45</div>

<div id="values"></div>

$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('#values').html($(this).text()):
});
```